# Which biometrics do UK border control store when EU citizens scan their passport at airport (both entering and leaving, from/to Europe)

Tags: airports, borders, customs-and-immigration, biometric-passports

Biometrics are not collected from the traveller itself, but passports are still being scanned by UK officials and these contain biometrics. Are such biometrics being (copied and) stored?

Comment: I assume the UK stores everything it scans. Why would it not?

Answer (score 1):

This https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/779876/borders-immigration-citizenship-system-privacy-notice.pdf sets out the approach to data capture and storage

“At the border, passenger name records data is retained for 5 years. Advance passenger information may be retained for 10 years. Arrest and detention records may be held for 6 years.”

Comment: Thank you very much, I came across this document already. However no information is provided about biometrics, and therefore my questions remains unsolved...
Biometrics are indeed mentioned in the document that you cite "You supply a biometric (for example, fingerprints or a facial biometric)" and scanning a passport is indeed equivalent to supplying a biometric. No info about retention is mentioned.

Comment: @user103808 I’m happy to delete my answer since it hasn’t resolved your question. You should expand your question to include the research you’ve already done, so that would-be responders will know about it.

Comment: @user103808 they don't necessarily read any biometric information from the passport at all except for passports that are scanned at a  automatic gate, where the photograph is compared to the photograph they take while the traveler stands in front of the gate.